# Django convert String in Dictionary to Integer for the first 3 keys

Tags: django

Sorry for this newbie questions.

I have a dict like this:

> {'id':'1', 'Book':'21', 'Member':'3', 'Title':'Chameleon vol. 2',
> 'Author':'Jason Bridge'}

I want to convert that dict to:

> {'id':1, 'Book':21, 'Member':3, 'Title':'Chameleon vol. 2',
> 'Author':'Jason Bridge'}

I need to convert only the first 3 key value to int

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that will change all strings containing integers to integers within a dictionary, or specifically a way to change only the first three values to integers?

Comment: only certain values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict1 = {'id':'1', 'Book':'21', 'Member':'3', 'Title':'Chameleon vol. 2', 'Author':'Jason Bridge'}

y_dict = dict(list(dict1.items())[:3])
print(y_dict) #dict sliced to the first 3 items that their values will be converted
z_dict = dict(list(dict1.items())[3:])
print(z_dict) #the rest of item that their values will not be converted to integer
x_dict = {k:int(v) for k, v in y_dict.items()}
print(x_dict) # dict values converted to integer
w_dict = {**x_dict, **z_dict} 
print(w_dict) # merge of first 3 items with values as integer and the rest of the dict intact
```

**w_dict** is the result you are looking for.

Comment: Perfect... this is what I am looking for.. Thanks mate...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your dict stored in "book_data" variable.
What means first 3 keys?
If you have static keys, you can set manually for it:

```
for key in ['id', 'Book', 'Member']:
    book_data[key] = int(book_data[key])
```

If you have mutable dictionary, you may get it with it:

```
for key, val in list(book_data.items())[:3]:
    book_data[key] = int(val)
```

method `items` help you avoid iterate over values.

Comment: then how can I use something like this ?    --->  .update(**book_data) since I have 5 keys in book_data

Comment: You stored your dictionary somehow. Change `book_data` on `{'id':'1', 'Book':'21', 'Member':'3', 'Title':'Chameleon vol. 2', 'Author':'Jason Bridge'}` if you want avoid to create a variable.